# Extracting blocks of data after fix step from Molecular Dynamics

Tags: extract, data-extraction

I am newbie in bash programming. My problem is the following:
I have a trajectory file in xyz extension, out of a molecular dynamics calculation. In this file there are, more or less, 2000 blocks of coordinates. Each block of coordinate start with the number of atoms and end with the same number of atoms reported, e.g. of a block:

352    (starting point first block)

i =   0,

...

...

352     (ending point first block/starting point second block)

i =   10,

...

...

352

out of this file, I would like to be able to grep some of the blocks/configurations along the all trajectory file, at a fix ratio, lets say, every 10 configurations ( so that in the end I have 200 sampled structures from the beginning to the end of the trajectory file).

I thought, but again, I am not an expert, to use a for loop like:

```
for i in .xyz
  do (grep "352
     \n.*some_pattern.*
     \n.*352");
done
```

The point is that I have no idea on 1st how to tell the script to grep the block and 2nd to extract the blocks every 10 configurations.
Can you kindly help me?

P.S. while for the first point I think after sometime I will be able to fix it, the second is the most annoying.